# I want to split string without creating two strings

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split String without creating string array. Below is code

```
String output = "abc 0 0 222.1.2.3:12345 1.1.3.5:20000 55555";
        JSONArray listeningIpsArray = new JSONArray();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(output)) {
            String[] lines = output.split("\n");
            for (String line : lines) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                    String[] port = output.split("\\:");
                    for (String l : port) {
                        listeningIpsArray.put(l.trim());
                    }
                }
            }
            // String a[] =output.split("\\:");
            System.out.println("String" + listeningIpsArray);
        }
    }
```

When I run this code I got output as below. Array of 3 String elements is being created

```
String["abc 0 0 222.1.2.3","12345 1.1.3.5","20000 55555"]
```

But I need output in only one string as below.

```
String["abc 0 0 222.1.2.3 12345 1.1.3.5 20000 55555"]
```

Space between IP and port.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why do you have `String[] port = output.split("\\:");` if you don't want that?

Comment: Why dont you replace ":" with space." " String a = "abc 0 0 222.1.2.3:12345 1.1.3.5:20000 55555";    String r = a.replace(":"," "); System.out.println(r);

Comment: use StringBuilder and append all the splitted strings to builder with space and finally add it to listeningIpsArray as listeningIpsArray.put(builder.toString());

Comment: if you really need to split the string, I would recommend to use StringUtils.join to join the strings by space after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `String output = "abc 0 0 222.1.2.3:12345 1.1.3.5:20000 55555";` is your input, and you want `"abc 0 0 222.1.2.3 12345 1.1.3.5 20000 55555"` as output, all you have to do is use `output.replace(":", " ")` i.e., simply replace all the colons with space. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use replace instead of split method for your purpose:

```
String output = "abc 0 0 222.1.2.3:12345 1.1.3.5:20000 55555";
JSONArray listeningIpsArray = new JSONArray();
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(output)) {
    String[] lines = output.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
            listeningIpsArray.put(l.trim().replace(":"," "));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("String" + listeningIpsArray);
}
```